# When SSIS is saving a PDF from an SSRS, the PDF is corrupted

Tags: sql-server, pdf, reporting-services, ssis

We do not have SSRS Enterprise and I am developing this all in VS2017.
I have the SSRS report uploaded to the server and working perfectly.
I can copy/paste the URL into IE and it will run the report with the parameters specified, so I believe that the URL is correct.

From the SQL Reporting Services webpage I can click the Export and choose PDF and it will save it as a PDF correctly. Same thing with Excel, it will export it as Excel correctly.

However, when I try to create the PDF through SSIS, it will create the file with the correct filename in the correct folder, so it looks good, but it isnt.

If I try and open the PDF it will come back as corrupted.

I did find something ([SSRS PDF Export. There was an error opening this document. This file is damaged and could not be repaired](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6f750009-cd8e-4329-9d82-809c3c26795d/ssrs-pdf-export-there-was-an-error-opening-this-document-this-file-is-damaged-and-could-not-be?forum=sqlreportingservices)) that said to change permissions on some DLL's to have full access and not just read/write so I went and changed the permissions for domain\Administrators to have full access to the two DLLs and that didnt make a difference

Here is the URL that is passed to the code:

```
http://XXXX/Reports/report/ScheduledReports/WeeklySalesInvoiced_PDF?StartDate=07%2F08%2F2019&EndDate=07%2F12%2F2019&TerritoryID=101&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF
```

Here is the code that is supposed to create the PDF:

```
Protected Sub SaveFile(ByVal url As String, ByVal localpath As String)
Dim loRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
Dim loResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
Dim loResponseStream As System.IO.Stream
Dim loFileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(localpath, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
Dim laBytes(256) As Byte
Dim liCount As Integer = 1
Try

    loRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
    loRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    loRequest.Timeout = 600000
    loRequest.Method = "GET"
    loResponse = CType(loRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
    loResponseStream = loResponse.GetResponseStream
    Do While liCount > 0
        liCount = loResponseStream.Read(laBytes, 0, 256)
        loFileStream.Write(laBytes, 0, liCount)
    Loop

    loFileStream.Flush()
    loFileStream.Close()

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
End Sub
```

When I open the PDF in notepad++ this is what I see (which is not anything like what is in the report):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="portal" ng-controller="MainController as main" lang="{{main.getLanguage()}}" ng-class="{'flex':main.needsCssFlex}" ng-strict-di resizer>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=ed
```

I tried to save it as Excel and it ended up with the exact same thing in it. It would be corrupt and Excel would ask to open it anyway, I say yes just open it and I see the same thing as what is in the PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a default SSRS install, you are navigating to http://server/Reports and it looks something like

[image: SSRS 2016 home page]

That is the web portal for users to manage all things SSRS.

There is a second site associated with SSRS and this is the one you should be pointing to as it handles the "actual" work http://server/ReportServer It should look something like this

[image: SSRS Web Server]

Rebuild your URL using the ReportServer location and I suspect you'll get a viable PDF/Excel document. Right now, you're just downloading the wrapper page from the web portal.